# How to map the errorBody automatically using coverter factory?

Tags: android, json, retrofit, converters, error-code

I'm using **retrofit** to fetch some data from a remote server, when the response code is something other than `200` for success, the body returns as `null`.
I found out in this case I should get my result from `response.errorBody()` but it returned in a raw **JSON** form of course, is there anyway to map it automatically using the **GsonConverterFactory** that I included in my retrofit instance?

```
mApiServices.register(builder.build()).enqueue(new Callback<LoginModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<LoginModel> call, Response<LoginModel> response) {
            if (response.code() == 200 && response.body() != null && response.body().getStatus() == 1) {
                LoginModel.Data data = response.body().getData();
                mDataLiveData.setValue(data);
                saveToSharedPref(data);
            } else {
                String errorBody = null;
                try {
                    errorBody = response.errorBody().string();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            resetIsLoading();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<LoginModel> call, Throwable t) {
            mGeneralError.setValue(t.getMessage());
            resetIsLoading();
        }
    });
```

And here's how I instantiated the Retrofit instance

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("lang", PreferenceUtils.getLocaleKey(context)).build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    }).build();

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build();
    return retrofit;
```

Comment: put your code where you call retrofit

Comment: share your code where you implemented retrofit network logic

Comment: Please share the code and model to which you want your error to be part of.

Comment: I did now, please re-check it